# iPad: Time lag between portrait and landscape modes

Tags: ios, ipad, html, css

I have an iPad application with HTML5 home screen. I need to create two different design templates for landscape and portrait modes. I use CSS `@media` with `orientation : landscape` and `orientation : portrait`. And it works great for me. But I have a time lag when I change the device's orientation. And as result I can see wrong elements sizes across one or two seconds.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a link? I'd like to see the said effect duplicated on my iPad.

Comment: @Ceane Lamerez: Unfortunately I can't share the link. I signed a NDA document.

Comment: Fortunately, I've been able to recreate the same effect. It seems that Safari needs time to render and display the new changes.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this problem? I actually do not think it's possible by now, but in case you have found something out, it would be great if you could share that! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

When I removed `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >`, the lag between orientations disappeared, 100%, (using iPad2, iOS6, Safari browser).

After more trial & error, I found that the `initial-scale` was causing the lag. Why? Outside of my knowledge base. This is just what I found.  However, I now have to makeup for that `initial-scale=1` with more CSS styles per `portrait/landscape` orientation.

The browser visually decreases everything to fit in `portrait` and expands in `landscape` mode.

Here's a [great article about viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html).

Comment: I can confirm removing `initial-scale` fixed the lag issue for me, even with the following:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late to the game, but (at least on more recent versions of iOS - 6+) I've had much better luck when declaring all viewport scale properties:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

With all of these declared, transitioning between portrait and landscape is much smoother with much less lag.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't fix this lag you can try to make it smoothly with a annimation effect on orientation change.

First in your CSS apply a transformation property too all your selecteur thats will move

```
#container, #header h1, #header h2, #header h3 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

You can take a look to [my website](http://catherine-baras.fr/) where I use this technic

Comment: Thank you, but the site doesn't scale properly.